# Dev Tools, Inspect Element, why is my CSS unchecked?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, firefox-developer-tools

On a freshly loaded site, when I go inspect an element, a CSS property is always unchecked. It's there and I can enable it, but it's unchecked by default.

The style is `position: sticky`

Tried this in different browsers:
 * Chrome and Firefox: it's unchecked, but I can toggle it
 * Safari: it's "commented out" and also I can toggle it

To be clear: I don't see any other `position` styles being applied on that same element.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions like that are generally unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve), which is why making effort to create it often solves the problem. You already solved it so it would make sense to retroactively add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - the style was actually commented out in code.

What surprised my was Dev Tools picking up commented out styles and listing it.

Updated: as @sebastian-zartner pointed out, these commented out styles will always be displayed

Comment: This is not related to source maps. Commented out style declarations always get displayed disabled in the DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

An element with position: sticky; is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).

Safari requires a -webkit- prefix

Comment: On different pages of the site, the prefix-less syntax is working. (Safari 13.1.1)

Comment: This is a good explanation for how `position: sticky;` works, though this is not the reason why some style declarations are commented out in the DevTools.